# Question about proving the following proposition

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am learning proofs and have the following proposition:

> For all $m\in\mathbb Z$, $m\times 0 = 0 = 0\times m$

Is it asking me to first prove that $m\times0 = 0$? Because $m\times 0 = 0 \times m$ is an axiom.

Comment: Technically $m\times 0=0\times m$ is usually not given as an axiom. Usually you have a more general axiom that multiplication is commutative. But it is very simple to prove $m\times 0=0\times m$ using that axiom; it takes only one step if you are allowed to substitute two variables at once. The more interesting part, however, is (as you thought) the proof that $m\times 0=0$.

Comment: What properties are you presupposing in your proof? What's your starting point?

Answer (score 1):

I think that I have figured it out!

For all $m\in\mathbb Z$, $m\times 0 = 0 = 0\times m$

\begin{align*}
m\times 0 &= m\times 0\\
m\times 0 &= m\times (m +(-m))\\
m\times 0 &= (m \times m) + (m \times -m)\\
m\times 0 &= m^2 - m^2\\
m\times 0 &= 0
\end{align*}

What do you think? Then I can use the commutativity axiom to state:

\begin{align*}
m\times 0&=0 &=0\times m
\end{align*}

Comment: This is good. It is important to note that in this proof you are using a few facts: (1) $\forall x$, there exists some $(-x)$ such that $x + (-x) = 0$, (2) the distributive law, and (3) $\forall x,y$, we have $x \times (-y) = -xy$.